# Microsoft Edge Browser opens Angular application in compatibility mode: IE 11

Tags: angular, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, ng-build

I am trying to run the angular application in Microsoft Edge browser(created build ng build --prod), but the application is opening in compatibility mode: IE 11.
If I run the application locally(command - ng serve) the application is behaving correctly (opening in edge browser without any compatibility mode), Please suggest if there any configuration changes/code change required for the production build.

Comment: You can check whether your app is using `<!DOCTYPE html>` or not. Further, try to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. I want to confirm with you whether your site is hosted on the intranet? It can cause this behavior. also, let us know which exact version of the Edge browser you are using for making this test?

Comment: Yes there is <!doctype html> and <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> tags added in index.html file. Site is hosted on live web server. I am using Edge 85.0.564.44(Offical build)(64-bit)

Comment: We can see that you are using the Edge Chromium browser and the site gets opened with the IE 11 mode. It can be possible that the site is added to the **Enterprise mode site list**. I suggest you check the site list file and if your site is listed there then try to remove it from the list may help to fix the issue. To find the location of the site list file check this [group policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy). [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-sitelist)

Comment: Thanks Deepak, will verify suggested setings.

Comment: Let us know whether the suggestion works for you or not.